# How to use Loopback ACL model/table?

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs

I'm trying to setup access control for my rest API. Loopback provides a great starting point for handling access based on user/role/principals.

But what if I want anything more than provided, e.g. multiple owners for a model instance? Would adding entries to the ACL table be enough? Or should I create a new role/resolver, and if so, can/should I reuse the existing ACL model/table or roll my own?

Loopback is awesome, but documentation lacks depth, ending you up reading the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Well in this particular case I suggest creating a custom role resolver.

Something like this:

```
Role.registerResolver('$inOwners', function (role, ctx, callback) {
  ctx.model.count({
    id: ctx.modelId,

    // This only works for mongo db...
    owners: ctx.accessToken.userId
  }, function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else if (count) {
      callback();
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not Owner'));
    }
  });
});
```

And then you can either add this to the acls(Either in the models static acls, in the json file, or add it to the ACL table):

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$inOwners",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "*",
  "model": "*"
}
```

Do remember, that whenever the access to a loopback method depends on what's inside a document/row then you can only use role resolvers to define ACL for it, else you have to make your own ACL system.

Comment: Thank you! :). 
Am I correct in understanding this as the ACL table is basically "just" a persistance of what is specified in the model json files?
Your example uses a field in the model that will contain the owners of the object. If I want more control, e.g. owners, editors, viewers of individual instances, this would probably go in a new "instance_acl" table?

Comment: Yes it is. You'd use the ACL table for dynamic stuff(for example the admin can manage the permission for other users), and the ones are in model json files, are just for static stuff. For more control, you can make more specific acl entries or you can add more logic in the role resolver.